# Unnamed classes

Tags: c++, class

Motivated by the [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606902/cant-make-sense-of-large-integer-struct)

The grammar for C++ classes is defined as

`class-key identifier *[opt]* base-clause *[opt]*`  (Italics are mine)

This to me means that the class name is option and we can have unnamed classes in C++.

So, is the following well-formed?

```
struct X{
   struct{
      int x;
      int y;
   };
};

int main(){}
```

> VS: error C2467: illegal declaration
>   of anonymous 'struct'
>
> Comeau online: error: declaration does
>   not declare anything
>        struct{
>
> GCC(ideone): Compiles fine

Any thoughts?

Comment: works under Borland C++ 5.6.4 (C++Builder 6)

Comment: For VS please check with extensions disabled (/Za)

Comment: I don't have gcc here. Does it work with -pedantic also?

Comment: Our code is illegal in C++ (as well as in C), even tough it is a popular extension in many C/C++ compilers. All compilers will issue a diagnostic, if you disable language extension or increase the warning level.

Comment: Since this code doesn't make any sense (how do you refer to the struct if you don't have any object?) I don't see where the problem is. Try declaring an object of this type by inserting the object's name between `}` and `;`.

Comment: @sellibitze: The intended functionality is that the members of anonymous struct become members of `X` (as would be the case in case of anonymous union). It is indeed useful at times, when declaring unions (see example in Blindy's answer). Nevertheless it is illegal in C++.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it is not well-formed. You cannot derive the language syntax from these grammar statements alone. The extra requirements are given in the text of the standard also have to be taken into account. In this case that would be

> **7 Declarations**
>
> ...
>
> **3**   In a *simple-declaration*, the optional *init-declarator-list* can be
> omitted only when declaring a class
> (clause 9) or enumeration (7.2), that
> is, when the *decl-specifier-seq*
> contains either a *class-specifier*, an
> *elaboratedtype-specifier* with a
> *class-key* (9.1), or an *enum-specifier*.
> In these cases and whenever a
> *class-specifier* or *enum-specifier* is
> present in the *decl-specifier-seq*, the
> identifiers in these specifiers are
> among the names being declared by the
> declaration (as *class-names*,
> *enum-names*, or *enumerators*, depending
> on the syntax). **In such cases, and
> except for the declaration of an
> unnamed bit-field (9.6), the
> *decl-specifier-seq* shall introduce one
> or more names into the program, or
> shall redeclare a name introduced by a
> previous declaration**.

The last sentence is the one that matters in this case

The "optional" part is only there to allow declarations like

```
struct { int x; } s;
typedef struct { int x, y; } Point;
```

The first one which declares a class type with no linkage and variable `s` of that type. Note that types with no linkage cannot be used to declare a variable with linkage, meaning that such declaration cannot be used in namespace scope.

Your example is ill-formed, but this would be legal

```
struct X {
   struct {
      int x;
      int y;
   } point;
};
```

Also, nameless class syntax is used to declare anonymous unions (although I'm a bit puzzled by the fact that 7/3 does not mention anonymous unions).

Answer (score 0):

That code is actually valid in MSVC, you must have compiled in a restricted mode.

And while I would most likely never use them, they do allow for some interesting usage, like this:

```
X obj;
obj.x=1;
obj.y=2;
```

They're used for example in the `LARGE_INTEGER` class, only it's an `union` instead. This way you can avoid sub-objects when all you really want is one member to be splittable into smaller pieces.

The `LARGE_INTEGER` declaration as a visual example:

```
#if defined(MIDL_PASS)
typedef struct _LARGE_INTEGER {
#else // MIDL_PASS
typedef union _LARGE_INTEGER {
    struct {
        DWORD LowPart;
        LONG HighPart;
    };
    struct {
        DWORD LowPart;
        LONG HighPart;
    } u;
#endif //MIDL_PASS
    LONGLONG QuadPart;
} LARGE_INTEGER;
```

As far as I know however, this isn't valid standard C++, it's only allowed as extensions in gcc and msvc.